# Box-shadow leaving blank space in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I'm trying to add shadows to an image in Wordpress (Gutenberg). But when adding the box-shadow property it appears a space between the image and its shadow (see screenshot attached).

[Box-shadow not working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivgq0.png)

I also attach the code I'm using:

```
box-shadow: 10px 14px 28px #039BE5;
```

What am I doing wrong? I want the shadow to be next to the image without any space inbetween.

Comment: make sure to stretch the image to fill the container

Comment: And isn't there anther way to set the box-shadow to the outer div and achieve the same result? This way my client can easily apply a CSS class with Wordpress and he doesn't need to modify HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

You must set the box-shadow to the `img` not to outer div.